# Why is 見 replaced with 见 from simplified to traditional Chinese?

Tags: simplified-characters, traditional-vs-simplified

I'm trying to find out why certain (parts of) characters were replaced with others while developing the simplified Chinese writing system.

I want to know why 见 replaces 見? As in 问题，問題.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Wikipedia](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E7%AE%80%E5%8C%96%E5%AD%97),
来自于行书与草书的楷书化.

[注 1] lists some examples, 许多偏旁如讠[訁]、饣[飠]、纟[糹]、钅[釒]、呙[咼]、见[見]、页[頁]、贝[貝]、车[車]、东[東]、门[門]、马[馬]等来自草书。

Some simplifications were based on popular cursive forms (草书) embodying graphic or phonetic simplifications of the traditional forms. (from the [English version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_Chinese_characters) of the Wikipedia page)

Therefore, 见 replaces 見 because 见 is the cursive form of 見.

Comment: The one decides to simplify Chinese characters is absolutely an idiot.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Anywhere I can find more of the logic behind cursive forms ?

Answer (score 1):

You're asking "why did a committee (委員會) make a specific decision?"  The answer is "because it was a committee."  There is no explanation, that's just what the committee decided.  It's important to remember that simplified characters were devised by a committee.

In this case the committee went with "**Preserving the basic outline or shape of the original character**".

This might or might not be helpful:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_Chinese_characters

Comment: The committee makes this decision, because they are full of moron.